# Architectural decision regarding Repository pattern (it is using Automapper)

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, automapper, repository-pattern

I have:

1. Domain models (Model)
2. Database entities (Entity)
3. Repository: that accepts the model and converts it to the database entity (using automapper) and saves it to the database. In some cases returns back a Model object.

Example:

```
public class BaseRepository<T, U> : IRepository<T, U>
{
        public void Insert(T model)
        {            
            U entity= Mapper.Map<T, U>(model);
            dbContext.Set<U>().Add(entity);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Now when creating repository objects from a business layer i would instantiate the repository as:

```
new BaseRepository<Model, Entity>()
```

**PROBLEM**
Now this requires that the business layer have access to both the model and database entity projects. I want to avoid the reference of database entity to the business layer. My business layer should be able to instantiate repositories using only the domain model.

```
new BaseRepository<Model>()
```

for which i need a repository as

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
```

But then i cant find a way to handle the mapping between model and entity(automapper).

Is what i am asking valid? OR is my requirement absurd?

Note: I think my business layer should not have a reference to database entities because i do not want anyone using database entities directly. They should be working only with the model classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the answer is simple. Bit of a silly question to begin with. The declaration for IRep was wrong.

```
BaseRep<T,U>:IRep<T> instead of IRep<T, U>.
```

1. The rep interface should be:

   ```
   public interface IRepository<T>
       where T : class
   {
       void Insert(T model);           
       IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
   }
   ```
2. The base repository should be:

   ```
       public class BaseRepository<T, U> : IRepository<T>
               where T : class
               where U : class
       {
       protected readonly IPARS_ADOEntities dbContext;

       public BaseRepository()
           : this(new IPARS_ADOEntities())
       {

       }

       public BaseRepository(IPARS_ADOEntities dbContext)
       {
           this.dbContext = dbContext;
       }

       public void Insert(T model)
       {            
           U entity = Mapper.Map<T, U>(model);
           dbContext.Set<U>().Add(entity);
           dbContext.SaveChanges();
       }            

       public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
       {
           IEnumerable<U> entities = dbContext.Set<U>();
           return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<U>, IEnumerable<T>>(entities);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the business layer:

   ```
   public class BizLayer 
   {
       public List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployee(IRepository<EmployeeModel> rep)
       {
           return rep.GetAll();
       }    
    }
   ```
4. From the presentation or application root you inject the dependency:

   ```
   bizlayer.GetEmployees(new IRepository<EmployeeModel, EmployeeEntity>())
   ```

Comment: Weird... your presentation layer should be aware of what exact repository to pass to the business operations??

Comment: It could be the service layer in another architecture

Comment: I know, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: What does not make sense? See my note in the question. I do not want my business layer to access the Entity framework objects. Because i am using models or DTOs (whatever you want to call them). In other applications yes i have used the db entities in the business layer.

Comment: Look up constructor injection. Your business operations should not accept repository instances. Read a bit more here: http://codefizzle.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/correct-use-of-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Yeah. I know about it. That is just sample code with method injection. I was too lazy to type out everything.